# hidden and make visible a div with a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a problem with my jquery code.
i have a button and a div. the button muss open or close the div when i click. so i make a test to have the class of the div. when the div is hidden, i make it visible and hidden when the div is visible. Here is my code i don't know what is wrong

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-collapse">Left</button>
    <div id="mapBlock" class="hidden">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


    var classe = $('#mapBlock').attr('class');
     $('#btn-collapse').click(function() {
        if(classe == "hidden"){
          $('#mapBlock').removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");  
       }
       if(classe == "visible"){
          $('#mapBlock').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");  
       }
     });
});

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take the class each time clicking on the button

```
$('#btn-collapse').click(function() {
    var classe = $('#mapBlock').attr('class');
    if (classe == "hidden") {
        $('#mapBlock').removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
    }
    if (classe == "visible") {
        $('#mapBlock').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

It will be beeter to use `.hasClass()`

```
 $('#btn-collapse').click(function() {

        if ($('#mapBlock').hasClass("hidden")) {
            $('#mapBlock').removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        }
        if ($('#mapBlock').hasClass("visible")) {
            $('#mapBlock').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `toggle()` the visibility?

```
$('#btn-collapse').click(function() {
    $('#mapBlock').toggle(); 
});
```

Comment: don't you think you should explain what was wrong with OP's code rather than *just* providing another solution

Answer (score 0):

you could try the old toggleClass trick, this requires no knowledgfe of the *state* of the object and is always a binary toggle in either direction:

```
$('#btn-collapse').click(function() {
    $('#mapBlock').toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

on document ready you store the class attributes of #mapBlock in the variable 'classe'

this means that when you click the button it will always compare your if statements to what you saved from the start, it wont update each time. try putting the variable declaration inside your function and it should work.